# How to avoid docker mount /etc/hosts /etc/hostname /etc/resolv.conf automatically

Tags: docker

I was trying to share my GPGPU workstation with some friends. As they are using different environments, I was considering to using docker containers.

When running `df -h` in docker container, I find:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          10G   24K   10G   1% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.8G  8.1M  3.8G   1% /run
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /tmp
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda3       465G  6.2G  459G   2% /etc/hosts
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

I was surprised to find that `/dev/sda3` was mounted on `/etc/hosts` with host disk size visible. I was not willing to that be seen.

Though it can be umount by `rc.local` script or some service, but is there any method to avoid docker automatically mount it, let it managed absolutely by container, just like a normal virtual machine?

Docker version is `18.09.6, build 481bc77`

Docker container was started by:

```
docker run -it --net=macvlan -d --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --tmpfs /tmp --tmpfs /run --tmpfs /run/lock -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -e "container=docker" --device /dev/fuse -v /dev/hugepages:/dev/hugepages --runtime=runc --storage-opt "size=10G" ubuntu:16.04 /sbin/init
```

Dockerfile automatically fetched from docker hub without any change.

https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu

https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/010bf9649b1d10e2c34b159a9a9b338d0fdd4939/xenial/Dockerfile

Comment: What is your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Dockerfile is `ubuntu:16.04`, I have run `/sbin/init` in this docker, and set `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN`

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the full contents of the Dockerfile. Otherwise it is really hard to help. Also the command you used to build the image. Thank you?

Comment: When you start saying "totally isolate all details of the host from the container" and "run an unmodified OS image" and "run init within that" and even just the word "mount", a VM is probably a better fit than Docker.